# Do DataGridViewColumnCollections have an analogue for the ValueMember/DisplayMember distinction that comboboxes have?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView. In one column, I show my users `FooRealName` and that is what I want them to see. In my code, I almost always want to manipulate `FooID` instead of `FooRealName`. If this were a combobox, I'd exploit the ValueMember/DisplayMember distinction that they have. Do DataGridViewColumnCollections have anything analogous? Or am I forced to go down the messy path of defining an extra `FooID` column and keeping it invisible?

Comment: DisplayMember is a formatted value. The DGV allows to format the presentation of data, using a predefined format, specified for each Column, or using the `CellFormatting` event etc. You can do the same with the getter of the Property of a class object, the Expression of a DataColumn etc. The implementation depends on where FooRealName is coming from. Not sure how the `DataGridViewColumnCollection` (singular) is related to this

Comment: @Jimi Both `FooID` and `FooRealName` are populated from a call to a SQL server. I'm working on the assumption that the area to get the behaviour that I want is in the column's properties somewhere. At the end of the day, I'm just looking for a way to show my users `FooRealName` in the DataGridView while being able to use `FooID` in my code to refer to the exact same part of the DataGridView.

Comment: If these both are Columns coming from a query and you simply don't want to expose FooID, then I don't see the problem, just don't show that Column in the DGV. `FooID` is not presented but it's still there.

Comment: @Jimi The issue isn't exposing. The issue is that I want to be able to display `FooRealName` to my users but use `FooID` in my code that manipulates what the user is seeing. If I put `FooRealName` in one column and `FooID` in another, then I'm not achieving that goal. Think of it like the comboboxes mentioned in the question. When a user does something with the DisplayMember, my code can act as if they've selected the ValueMember.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. What is the relation between these two Columns? Is `FooID` the FK and you're retrieving the associated value with a JOIN? What do you want the User to do then? Set `FooRealName` to a different value, which then affects `FooID`, since it points to a different ID? If that's the case, can't you use a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn instead? Otherwise, explain in more details what kind of data you're dealing with and what you want to achieve (please, not in comments)

Comment: @Jimi Actually, that DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column idea might be exactly what I need! Thanks.